# C# linq get records where date range is in a selected week

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a `List<Holiday>` holidays that has the following properties:

- HolidayId
- StartDate
- EndDate

On the other hand I have the following code that generates all Dates in the current weeek:

```
 int days = currentDate.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday;
 DateTime dtTemp = currentDate.AddDays(-days);
 weekDays.Add(dtTemp);

 // add all dates within the current week
 weekDays.AddRange(new DateTime[] {
     dtTemp.AddDays(1), dtTemp.AddDays(2), dtTemp.AddDays(3), dtTemp.AddDays(4), dtTemp.AddDays(5), dtTemp.AddDays(6)
 });
```

Now, I need to filter my `List<Holiday>` so I get only those records that has days in the current week.

For example:

> **Current Week: July 6 to July 12**
>
> Holiday 1: StartDate = '2014-07-10', EndDate='2014-07-22'

The above Holiday even it the EndDate is out of current week range there are days that will be in the current date so I should get that record.

> **Current Week: July 6 to July 12**
>
> Holiday 2: StartDate = '2014-07-04', EndDate='2014-07-06'

I also should get this record because July 6 is in the current week.

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int days = currentDate.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Sunday;
DateTime weekStart = currentDate.AddDays(-days);
DateTime weekEnd = weekStart.AddDays(6);

return holidays.Where(h=>h.StartDate <= weekEnd && h.EndDate >= weekStart);
```

This differs from AD.Net's solution (and OPs expectation) in that we don't need to create a list of all days in the week at all. It also requires fewer comparisons in most cases, so it could be faster in cases where that matters.

Answer (score 4):

```
holidays.Where(h=>weekDays.Any(w=>h.StartDate >= w && h.EndDate <= w))
```